# Sharepoint List - condition between two cells

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to create a condition between two columns in a Sharepoint list.I have one column called "Affected" (yes/no) and the other one called "impact info" (free text). I want to create a condition in which the user will have to fill in the details in the "impact info" column but only if he chose "yes" in "affected".
Can anybody tell me how should I do that?
Thanks!!!

Comment: I haven't done this myself, but looking at Column Validation might me a good starting point: http://spradip.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/validation-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: when I try to do it through the validation functionality I get an error: "the formula cannot refer to another column"

Answer (score 0):

You may refer this following link

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomization/thread/4da1f538-a35f-479e-b1dc-b0b32b2a16a5